# Permissions for tar extraction

Tags: pi-3, golang

I just got a  raspberry pi 3 and I am trying to install golang 1.8.5. However, when I tried to extract the tar.gz file to the usr/local/ directory, I got an error message saying that I did not have the permissions to extract the file to the directory. How do I get the extraction permissions?

Answer (score 1):

Use `su` (super user) before the extraction command as you don't have write permission for /usr/local.